# MySQL is inserting "" as 0 in decimal fields. How to stop that?

Tags: mysql, null

The fields are nullable, so they do allow nulls.

Why would MySQL convert "" to 0 instead of NULL?

Is there a way to force it to be NULL instead?

Comment: Are you getting an error message like `ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect decimal value: '' for column 'price' at row 1` ?

Comment: Empty string is no more like `NULL` than it is like `0` and arguably even less so.   If you want null, why exactly would you not insert null?

Answer (score 2):

This seems be an on-going bug although it is not considered a bug, such as [Bug #73041: Error 1366 when loading null into columns with decimal type using strict mode](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73041)

According to [Oracle's MySQL Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/constraint-invalid-data.html)

> If you are not using strict mode, then whenever you insert an “incorrect” value into a column, such as a NULL into a NOT NULL column or a too-large numeric value into a numeric column, MySQL sets the column to the “best possible value” instead of producing an error:
>
> The following rules describe in more detail how this works:
>
> If you try to store an out of range value into a numeric column, MySQL Server instead stores zero, the smallest possible value, or the largest possible value, whichever is closest to the invalid value.
>
> For strings, MySQL stores either the empty string or as much of the string as can be stored in the column.
>
> If you try to store a string that does not start with a number into a numeric column, MySQL Server stores 0.

That's also in the the [regular MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/constraint-invalid-data.html).

With rules like these, that's why a zero(0) pops up for an unspecified DECIMAL value.

If you look back at [the bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73041), someone got around it when using `\N` for null values while loading a CSV file with `LOAD DATA INFILE`.