# MySQL loading NULLs in numeric columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, datatypes, null

**MySQL 5.6.23, InnoDB**

I am loading tables from character delimited text files using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` commnd and I would like every field with a `\N`, which is the `NULL` character in this setting, to place a `NULL` in the table. Some numeric types have this behavior, whereas others place a `0`. I am using `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` and *some* columns do properly get `NULL` values, so it it not a fixed-row format issue.

These are the types I've observed while testing:

- `INT` inserts `NULL`s
- `DECIMAL(x,0)` inserts `NULL`s
- `DECIMAL(x,y)` inserts `0.0`s
- `FLOAT` inserts `0`s
- `DOUBLE(x,y)` inserts `0.0`s
- `DOUBLE` inserts `0`s

All of the columns in question are defined with `DEFAULT NULL`. I know that various functions could convert these `0`s into `NULL`s. **The question is whether there is a datatype that can handle decimal precision and will also insert `NULL`s on load.**

Additionally, I see a whole bunch of questions relating to misunderstanding of the difference between a string, an empty string, and a null value. ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19298027/544342) [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7459875/544342) [example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/87206/53784)) This is not the issue, as the `NULL`s are there and are loaded properly into the same column when I redefine it as DECIMAL(x,0), then improperly when defined as DECIMAL(x,3).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very short answer : No new datatypes have been created to accommodate you.

While we are on this subject

Let's try plain SQL

```
USE test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS numtest;
CREATE TABLE numtest
(
  id int not null auto_increment,
  xx decimal(10,3) default null,
  primary key (id)
);
INSERT INTO numtest (id) values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0);
SELECT * FROM numtest;
```

Does this work ???

```
mysql> USE test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS numtest;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE numtest
    -> (
    ->   id int not null auto_increment,
    ->   xx decimal(10,3) default null,
    ->   primary key (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO numtest (id) values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM numtest;
+----+------+
| id | xx   |
+----+------+
|  1 | NULL |
|  2 | NULL |
|  3 | NULL |
|  4 | NULL |
|  5 | NULL |
+----+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

OK, fine. It works with SQL. You are asking about `LOAD DATA INFILE`

You brought up a post I answered : [MySQL is inserting "" as 0 in decimal fields. How to stop that?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87206/mysql-is-inserting-as-0-in-decimal-fields-how-to-stop-that/87208#87208)

Let's see if that bug was addressed since it was submitted. I will try to duplicate the code in that bug that did not work.

First let's create that table from the bug report

```
mysql> USE test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bug_repeat;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE bug_repeat
    -> (
    ->   name varchar(10),
    ->   price decimal(12,6)
    -> )
    -> ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii COLLATE=ascii_bin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE bug_repeat\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: bug_repeat
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `bug_repeat` (
  `name` varchar(10) COLLATE ascii_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii COLLATE=ascii_bin
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Next, let's make some data

```
C:\>type C:\MySQLDBA\bug_test.txt
name,
name,0
,
name,6
name,2
name,
name,0
name,0
name,
name,0

C:\>
```

Let's run the LOAD DATA INFILE

```
mysql> load data local infile 'C:/MySQLDBA/bug_test.txt'
    -> into table test.bug_repeat
    -> fields terminated by ','
    -> lines terminated by '\n';
Query OK, 10 rows affected, 4 warnings (0.00 sec)
Records: 10  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 4
```

Ouch, what happened

```
mysql> show warnings\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1366
' for column 'price' at row 1lue: '
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1366
' for column 'price' at row 3lue: '
*************************** 3. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1366
' for column 'price' at row 6lue: '
*************************** 4. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1366
' for column 'price' at row 9lue: '
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from bug_repeat;
+------+----------+
| name | price    |
+------+----------+
| name | 0.000000 |
| name | 0.000000 |
|      | 0.000000 |
| name | 6.000000 |
| name | 2.000000 |
| name | 0.000000 |
| name | 0.000000 |
| name | 0.000000 |
| name | 0.000000 |
| name | 0.000000 |
+------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

What's the sql_mode ?

```
mysql> select @@sql_mode;
+------------------------+
| @@sql_mode             |
+------------------------+
| NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Let's blank out the sql_mode, truncate the table and reload

```
mysql> set sql_mode = '';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@sql_mode;
+------------+
| @@sql_mode |
+------------+
|            |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> truncate table bug_repeat;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> load data local infile 'C:/MySQLDBA/bug_test.txt'
    -> into table test.bug_repeat
    -> fields terminated by ','
    -> lines terminated by '\n';
Query OK, 10 rows affected, 4 warnings (0.02 sec)
Records: 10  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 4

mysql> show warnings\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1366
' for column 'price' at row 1lue: '
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1366
' for column 'price' at row 3lue: '
*************************** 3. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1366
' for column 'price' at row 6lue: '
*************************** 4. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1366
' for column 'price' at row 9lue: '
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Let doctor the input file with `\N` like the bug report had

```
C:\>type C:\MySQLDBA\bug_test.txt
name,\N
name,0
\N,\N
name,6
name,2
name,\N
name,0
name,0
name,\N
name,0

C:\>
```

Let's repeat all of this with InnoDB

```
mysql> USE test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bug_repeat;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE bug_repeat
    -> (
    ->   name varchar(10),
    ->   price decimal(12,6)
    -> )
    -> ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> truncate table bug_repeat;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> load data local infile 'C:/MySQLDBA/bug_test.txt'
    -> into table test.bug_repeat
    -> fields terminated by ','
    -> lines terminated by '\n';
Query OK, 10 rows affected, 4 warnings (0.00 sec)
Records: 10  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 4

mysql> show warnings\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1366
' for column 'price' at row 1lue: 'N
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1366
' for column 'price' at row 3lue: 'N
*************************** 3. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1366
' for column 'price' at row 6lue: 'N
*************************** 4. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1366
' for column 'price' at row 9lue: 'N
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from bug_repeat;
+------+----------+
| name | price    |
+------+----------+
| name | 0.000000 |
| name | 0.000000 |
| NULL | 0.000000 |
| name | 6.000000 |
| name | 2.000000 |
| name | 0.000000 |
| name | 0.000000 |
| name | 0.000000 |
| name | 0.000000 |
| name | 0.000000 |
+------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

What version of MySQL am I using ???

```
mysql> show global variables like 'version%';
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| version                 | 5.6.22                       |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Win64                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

What about Linux ???

```
$ cat /tmp/bug_test.txt
name,\N
name,0
\N,\N
name,6
name,2
name,\N
name,0
name,0
name,\N
name,0

$
```

Logging in to mysql and trying ...

```
mysql> create database test;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> USE test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bug_repeat;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE bug_repeat
    -> (
    ->   name varchar(10),
    ->   price decimal(12,6)
    -> )
    -> ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> truncate table bug_repeat;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> load data local infile 'C:/MySQLDBA/bug_test.txt'
    -> into table test.bug_repeat
    -> fields terminated by ','
    -> lines terminated by '\n';
ERROR 2 (HY000): File 'C:/MySQLDBA/bug_test.txt' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
mysql> show warnings\G
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from bug_repeat;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> truncate table bug_repeat;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> load data local infile '/tmp/bug_test.txt'
    -> into table test.bug_repeat
    -> fields terminated by ','
    -> lines terminated by '\n';
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 10  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show warnings\G
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from bug_repeat;
+------+----------+
| name | price    |
+------+----------+
| name |     NULL |
| name | 0.000000 |
| NULL |     NULL |
| name | 6.000000 |
| name | 2.000000 |
| name |     NULL |
| name | 0.000000 |
| name | 0.000000 |
| name |     NULL |
| name | 0.000000 |
+------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show global variables like 'version%';
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| version                 | 5.6.21-log                   |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Today's date ???

```
mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2015-06-25 18:48:10 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

It's been a year and one week since that bug report was submitted and nothing has changed.

My answer to [MySQL is inserting "" as 0 in decimal fields. How to stop that?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87206/mysql-is-inserting-as-0-in-decimal-fields-how-to-stop-that/87208#87208) still stands as of today.

You need to do this test against MySQL 5.6.23 and see if something has changed.

Comment: With regard to `LOAD DATA INFILE`, yes, it's the only way. Otherwise, numeric values that follow the IEEE  floating point format become 0. Since I pointed out the workaround (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87206/mysql-is-inserting-as-0-in-decimal-fields-how-to-stop-that/87208#87208), no has created an IEEE floating point datatype that can start out as NULL.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reproducible test. The answer to your last instruction is that apparently nothing has changed. Is there a rationale for this behavior? Why is it not considered a bug?

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, why did you `TRUNCATE` after `CREATE`ing in the last two examples?

Comment: I was keeping the same table structure to reload and try again but with `\N`. If you look at the workaround in the bug report, there is a `truncate bug_repeat;` befoe the second `LOAD DATA INFILE` attempt. Thus, I was trying to duplicate the test of the workaround.